# When $\delta(x,y)$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non negative function and $f \equiv0$ only at zero. Let $\delta(x,y)=f(x-y)$. Is $\delta$ a metric?

We know that $\delta$ is a metric, if it satisfies:

1. $\delta(x,y) \ge 0$
2. $\delta(x,y)= 0 \iff x=y$
3. $\delta(x,y)=\delta(y,x)$
4. $\delta(x,y) \le \delta(x,z) + \delta(z,y)$.

$\delta$ satisfies the first and second point in the list because the definition of $f$. If $\delta$ satisfies point three, we have that
$$f(x-y)=f(y-x)$$
If $y=0$ then $f(x)=f(-x)$ so $f$ is a even function.

For the fourth point, I only have that
$$f(x)-f(y) \le f(x-y) \le f(x)+f(y)$$
and
$$f(nx)\le nf(x)$$
for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.
I don't see how to obtain more information about $f$.

Comment: If you can define some particular non-negative function $f$ which does *not* satisfy one (or both) of the statements (3.) and (4.), then that example would show that $\delta(x,y)$ might not be a metric.

Comment: I think the question is about when $\delta$ is a metric, or maybe I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done some good work already. I will say that you should be aiming to prove your conditions are equivalent. For example, you say

> If $\delta$ satisfies point three, we have that ... $f$ is an even function.

You should also be trying to show that, if $f$ is an even function, then $\delta$ satisfies point three (which shouldn't be difficult). When you have a nice equivalent condition, that's when you know you can stop!

Let's look at condition 4. The conditions you have strike me as already necessary and sufficient, so you could conceivably just present the condition as is (with proof). I would suggest using the fact that $f$ must be an even function to simplify further:
$$f(x + y) \le f(x) + f(y). \tag{$\star$}$$
Note that, this implies
$$f(x - y) \le f(x) + f(-y) = f(x) + f(y),$$
since $f$ is even. It also implies
$$f(x) \le f(x - y) + f(y) \implies f(x) - f(y) \le f(x - y).$$
Finally, it implies, by induction, that $f(nx) \le nf(x)$. Let's establish that $(\star)$ is indeed equivalent to condition 4, given $f$ is even.

Suppose $(\star)$ holds. Then
\begin{align*}
\delta(x, y) &= f(x - y) \\
&= f(x - z + z - y) \\
&\le f(x - z) + f(z - y) \\
&= \delta(x, z) + \delta(z, y).
\end{align*}

Conversely, suppose condition (4) holds. That is,
$$\delta(x, y) \le \delta(x, z) + \delta(z, y) \iff f(x - y) \le f(x - z) + f(z - y).$$
If we choose $z = 0$, then we get
$$f(x - y) \le f(x - 0) + f(0 - y).$$
Replacing $y$ with $-y$ yields $(\star)$ as required. That is, $(\star)$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for 4.